# Is my code to create an array with increasing integer values correct?

Tags: java

I want to make sure I am writing the right program for this question. The question is

> Write code that will create an array of int of size n, and fill in the array with the values 1 to n. Note that this is different than the array indices, which go from `0` to `n-1`.

This is the code I have written: Is this correct?

```
public class shaky{
   public static void main(String args[]){
        int i;
        int j;
        int n = 10;
        int[] value = new int[n];

        for(i=0,j=1; i <= (n-1); i++,j++){
            value[i] = j;
            System.out.print(value[i]);
        }
  }  
}
```

Comment: you must compile your code

Comment: A quick read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411  (for classnames. Java prefers CamelCase..)

Answer (score 6):

You can use Java 8's stream.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    int[] a = IntStream.range(1, n+1).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this looks correct, but two things. (1) this can be done with just `i` (no `j` needed).

```
public class shaky
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {

   int i;
   int n = 10;
   int[] value = new int[n];

         for(i=0; i<n; i++)
         {
          value[i] = i+1;
          System.out.print(value[i]);
         }
  }  
}
```

(2) these types of questions should be posted on the [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Original code was correct, but this is better because it is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

yes this is correct and in the for loop instead of writing `i<n` you can also write

```
i<value.length

              for(i=0; i<value.length; i++)
```

Comment: Why would he want to do that? he already has a variable that determines the size.

Comment: @Dgrin91 I said this is another way

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] arr = new int[10];

         for(i=0; i<n; i++)
         {

            arr[i] = i+1;

         }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it correct, but can more simple:

```
public class shaky{
    /**
       More correct to use this way, because possible
       to reuse this code and to have more clean code in main part.
     */
    public static int [] initialize(int length){
        int [] result = new int [length];
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) result[i] = i+1;
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        for (int value: initialize(10)) System.out.print(value+" ");
    }  
}
```

Testing it:
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`